# Leer nodos Hijos XML

Tags: c#, xml, nodos

Tengo un problema al leer un nodo de un XML, estoy trabajando en el lenguaje c#.

Existe un nodo que tiene dos nodos hijos con el mismo nombre(impuesto) y se debe leer ambos nodos para completar un proceso, adjunto el ejemplo del XML.

```
<LineaDetalle>
 <NumeroLinea>12</NumeroLinea>
 <Codigo>2449005009900</Codigo>
 <CodigoComercial>
   <Tipo>01</Tipo>
   <Codigo>15000555</Codigo>
</CodigoComercial>
<Cantidad>8.000</Cantidad>
<UnidadMedida>Unid</UnidadMedida>
<UnidadMedidaComercial>UN</UnidadMedidaComercial>
<Detalle>FRESCOLE SURT 250ML 6PACK</Detalle>
<PrecioUnitario>2040.01000</PrecioUnitario>
<MontoTotal>16320.08000</MontoTotal>
<SubTotal>16320.08000</SubTotal>
<Impuesto>
  <Codigo>99</Codigo>
  <Tarifa>0.00</Tarifa>
  <Monto>764.16000</Monto>
</Impuesto>
<Impuesto>
  <Codigo>01</Codigo>
  <CodigoTarifa>08</CodigoTarifa>
  <Tarifa>13.00</Tarifa>
  <Monto>2220.95000</Monto>
</Impuesto>
<ImpuestoNeto>2985.11000</ImpuestoNeto>
<MontoTotalLinea>19305.19000</MontoTotalLinea>
</LineaDetalle>
```

adjunto código de lectura del XML

```
foreach (string text in files)
        {
            try
            {
                
                XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDocument.Load(text);
                
                ...
                ...

                foreach (XmlNode item in xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("LineaDetalle"))
                {
                    if (item["Impuesto"] == null)
                    {
                        ...
                    }                       
                    else if (item["Impuesto"]["Codigo"].InnerText == "01" && item["Impuesto"]["CodigoTarifa"].InnerText == "08")
                    {
                        ....
                    }
                    }
                    
                    }

                }
```

Se deben realizar la lectura de ambos nodos, pero al leer el primer nodo con el nombre impuesto, no se logra leer el siguiente nodo.

Agradezco su ayuda, saludos

Comment: Probaste hacer un foreach en vez del if item? Pues, como para recorrer cada ocurrencia del nodo Impuesto

Comment: quite varias líneas del if, pero son como 4 decisiones según los códigos que vienen dentro del nodo impuesto, he realizado un foreach pero me da error no me carga todo el nodo. 

//foreach (XmlNode xn3 in item.SelectNodes)
       //{
       // if (xn3.InnerText == "01" && xn3["CodigoTarifa"].InnerText == "03")
       // {
       //  .... 
       //  ...
       // }
       // else if (xn3["Codigo"].InnerText == "01" && item["Impuesto"]["CodigoTarifa"].InnerText == "08")
       // {
       // }
       //}

Comment: El código va en la pregunta. Mira que en los comentarios es... infumable :)

Comment: el primer nodo si te lo leé?

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, para este caso yo tengo esta idea, obtener por separado los atributos por el nombre "Impuesto" y recorrer la coleccion.

te dejo un ejemplo de consola, espero te sirva.

```
  string text = "<LineaDetalle>\r\n <NumeroLinea>12</NumeroLinea>\r\n <Codigo>2449005009900</Codigo>\r\n <CodigoComercial>\r\n   <Tipo>01</Tipo>\r\n   <Codigo>15000555</Codigo>\r\n</CodigoComercial>\r\n<Cantidad>8.000</Cantidad>\r\n<UnidadMedida>Unid</UnidadMedida>\r\n<UnidadMedidaComercial>UN</UnidadMedidaComercial>\r\n<Detalle>FRESCOLE SURT 250ML 6PACK</Detalle>\r\n<PrecioUnitario>2040.01000</PrecioUnitario>\r\n<MontoTotal>16320.08000</MontoTotal>\r\n<SubTotal>16320.08000</SubTotal>\r\n<Impuesto>\r\n  <Codigo>99</Codigo>\r\n  <Tarifa>0.00</Tarifa>\r\n  <Monto>764.16000</Monto>\r\n</Impuesto>\r\n<Impuesto>\r\n  <Codigo>01</Codigo>\r\n  <CodigoTarifa>08</CodigoTarifa>\r\n  <Tarifa>13.00</Tarifa>\r\n  <Monto>2220.95000</Monto>\r\n</Impuesto>\r\n<ImpuestoNeto>2985.11000</ImpuestoNeto>\r\n<MontoTotalLinea>19305.19000</MontoTotalLinea>\r\n</LineaDetalle>";
    
    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocument.LoadXml(text);
    
    foreach (XmlNode item in xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("LineaDetalle"))
    {
//aqui tu logica para los otros atributos
        foreach(XmlNode impuesto in xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Impuesto"))
        {
                if (impuesto["Codigo"].InnerText == "01" && impuesto["CodigoTarifa"].InnerText == "08")
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"codigo {impuesto["Codigo"].InnerText}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Codigo Tarifa {impuesto["CodigoTarifa"].InnerText}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Saludos.